# Cross-browser testing with testng.xml without repeating test and classes sections

Tags: java, selenium, unit-testing, testng

Is it possible to specify multiple browser as parameter for cross-browser testing in TestNG **without** repeating the test itself? As in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Cross-browser suite" verbose="1">
    <test name="Cross-browser test">
        <parameter name="browsers" value="chrome,msedge,firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="TestClass" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Of course I could always handle the `browsers` parameter to instantiate multiple `WebDrivers`, but doing so would make test execution times not be reliable anymore, as what would be repeated would be the actual test code instead of the test itself. This might prove be extremely useful when working with very large testng.xml files. Is there any way I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Unfortunately I can't use `@DataProvider` as I'm using the `browsers` parameter inside a `@BeforeMethod` method (that is, where I'm instantiating the WebDriver). Also, I'm already using DataProviders all across my test codebase to get test parameters from an .xlsx file.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45196345/5372079

Comment: @AbhishekDhoundiyal thank you for your contribution to the post! I updated with an edit section to explain why I can't use a DataProvider in this situation.

Comment: ok, In that case try to use  `@Factory` and try to load the same class with different data set.

Comment: It worked! I'm going to share the solution I came up with in the next few days, thanks to your comment.